# Is there an easy way of creating a transaction in NodeJs?

Tags: light-wallet, transactions

I'm trying to construct a transaction and send it to the network using NodeJs. I asked around and was told to take a look at [mymonero-core-js](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js). While it seems like the library is exactly what I need, I'm totally out of my depth here. It's too low-level and without any kind of docs. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Monero daemon and then connect to it with this [node.js client](https://github.com/cryptoshrimpi/monerod-js/blob/master/README.md)

You should also check out  [rx-monero-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-monero-wallet)

Both of these are reasonably documented